# STS 3.6.1 not able to upgrade m2e to 1.6

Tags: m2e, spring-tool-suite

I attempted to upgrade m2e to 1.6 using

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.6

and

http://repository.takari.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2e/1.6.0/N/LATEST/

Both barb at me with the following stack trace ( my workspace/.log

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-10-09 20:42:29.994
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.core.SpringProjectConfigurator.doConfigure(SpringProjectConfigurator.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.importProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.ImportMavenProjectsJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(ImportMavenProjectsJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.ImportMavenProjectsJob.runInWorkspace(ImportMavenProjectsJob.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject cannot be found by org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven_3.6.1.201408250730-RELEASE
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more

Since m2e 1.6 is not official release yet.  But it is important to resolve this problem first and pin point which side ( m2e or sts) should fix this issue

Comment: Can you provide a few steps how to reproduce this issue? I tried to update a fresh STS 3.6.2 installation to m2e 1.6 using the first of the two update sites that you mentioned. The installation worked and using STS with the updated m2e works as well. Therefore I wonder how to reproduce this.

Comment: In addition to that it might also be useful to open a console, switch to the OSGi Host Console, type in "ss" for short status, and look for bundles in the state "INSTALLED". If there is any, do a "diag <number of bundle>" to see that is going wrong under the hood.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with STS 3.6.2 on Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 with m2e 1.6.0-20141029-2111: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject cannot be found by org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven_3.6.2.201410090854-RELEASE

Comment: The same issue with STS 3.6.4.CI-B36 (Build Id: 201501101206). I have several projects with "Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml.". Around 50. On Update I have the exception and then one project is updated. So after update I have 49 projects with error :)

Comment: Here is the related issue: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4007

Comment: This seems to be an issue caused by an update of m2e components and optional package imports not being wired again after the update. See https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4007 for more details.